# TypeError: Cannot call method 'toFixed' of undefined, JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript

Im taking an online coding course and I keep getting this error:

```
Line 18, TypeError: Cannot call method 'toFixed' of undefined
```

Not sure what is going wrong. Here is the full code:

```
//Calculate the area of a rectangle
function calculateArea(length, width) {
  return length * width;
}

function calculateTileCount(tileWidth,length,width)
{
  var tileArea = tileWidth * tileWidth
  var tileCount = calculateArea(length, width) / tileArea;
}

var bathroom1 = calculateTileCount(0.3, 5, 3);
var bathroom2 = calculateTileCount(0.3, 6.5, 3.5);
var bathroom3 = calculateTileCount(0.45, 9, 4);
var bathroom4 = calculateTileCount(0.45, 11, 4);

console.log('Bathroom Tiling' +
  '\nBathroom 1: ' + bathroom1.toFixed(0) +
  '\nBathroom 2: ' + bathroom2.toFixed(0) +
  '\nBathroom 3: ' + bathroom3.toFixed(0) +
  '\nBathroom 4: ' + bathroom4.toFixed(0));
```

Any help is much appreciated,
-Morgan

Comment: Your function returns nothing

Comment: More accurately, your function returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

You should `return tileCount;`

```
function calculateTileCount(tileWidth,length,width)
{
  var tileArea = tileWidth * tileWidth
  var tileCount = calculateArea(length, width) / tileArea;
  return tileCount;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFYRv/).